# C# generic constraint for Type to be castable

Tags: c#, generics

Is there a way with C# generics to limit a type `T` to be castable from another type?

**Example**:
Lets say I am saving information in the registry as a `string`, and when I restore the information I would like to have a function that looks something like that:

```
static T GetObjectFromRegistry<T>(string regPath) where T castable from string 
{
    string regValue = //Getting the registry value...
    T objectValue = (T)regValue;
    return objectValue ;
}
```

Comment: There is no such constraints in .NET

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no such type of constraints in .NET. There is only six types of constraints available (see [Constraints on Type Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx)):

- `where T: struct` type argument must be a value type
- `where T: class` type argument must be a reference type
- `where T: new()` type argument must have a public parameterless constructor
- `where T: <base class name>` type argument must be or derive from the specified base class
- `where T: <interface name>` type argument must be or implement the specified interface
- `where T: U` type argument supplied for T must be or derive from the argument supplied for U

If you want to cast string to your type, you can do casting to object first. But you can't put constraint on type parameter to make sure this casting can occur:

```
static T GetObjectFromRegistry<T>(string regPath)
{
    string regValue = //Getting the regisstry value...
    T objectValue = (T)(object)regValue;
    return objectValue ;
}
```

Another option - create interface:

```
public interface IInitializable
{
    void InitFrom(string s);
}
```

And put it as constraint:

```
static T GetObjectFromRegistry<T>(string regPath) 
  where T: IInitializable, new()
{
    string regValue = //Getting the regisstry value...   
    T objectValue = new T();
    objectValue.InitFrom(regValue);
    return objectValue ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Types are determined during compilation. You can't change the types during runtime. It is possible to cast object to its base or child class

Ref -

[Difference between object a = new Dog() vs Dog a = new Dog()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8556651/difference-between-object-a-new-dog-vs-dog-a-new-dog)

Comment: I realize that Types are determined at compilation time. but at compilation time you can also now the type reference passed to the function. (in the same manner that. string a = "abc", a[0] will work while (a as object)[0] won't ) So I don't really see how this answers the question...

Answer (score 0):

Constraints spell out like "the type of T must either be of type U or inherit type U", so the constraint you are looking for isn't doable.

*everything* is "castable" to `String` anyway, through `.ToString()` (YMMV)

Comment: **YMMV explained:** `.ToString()` is more or less an inbuilt debugging-feature. "[It converts an object to its string representation so that it is suitable for display.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring.aspX)" - MSDN. I strongly advise against (ab-)using it for casting.